Programatically accepting VS Code suggestions
I am making a speech-to-code VS Code extension and one of the features I want to add is to accept a suggestion when the user says a certain command.
However, I've been unable to get it to work. My ideas to  make this work were:
Accept it using a VS Code command:
vscode.commands.executeCommand('acceptSelectedSuggestion');

or:
vscode.commands.executeCommand('insertBestCompletion');

But I can't seem to get it to work
